# newcommand titlespacing

Tags: spacing, sectioning

To generate space between \section i am using \titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{1cm}{0.5cm}, doing the same for subsection. Is it possible to generate titlespacing between own commands? I need three blank lines before "Notes" and one after "Notes"

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}


% Spacing between section and text
% Syntax: \titlespacing*{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0cm}{1cm}{0.5cm}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{1cm}{1cm}


 %ENDNOTENLAYOUT%
\renewcommand\enoteformat{\noindent\setlength\hangindent{0.5cm}\makebox[0.5cm][l]{\theenmark\,}}
\def\enotesize{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{\normalsize\textit{Notes}}
\let\footnote=\endnote


\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}


\section{Beispiel}
\lipsum[1]


\subsection*{Endnotes}
\footnote{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[2]
\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1]

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that it is not recommended to use `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. So I will use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change the skips before and after the section titles.

`\enoteheading` uses `\section*` for the note heading. So you can prepend a `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to get the desired result. Note that I am not sure if `\enoteheading` should be really on the same sectioning level as `\section`? But because of the star there is no TOC entry and no section number. So maybe it is not a problem.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\enoteheading{%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[
      beforeskip=3\baselineskip,
      afterskip=\baselineskip,
      font=\normalsize\itshape
    ]{section}%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Notes}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1cm,
  afterskip=1cm
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1cm,
  afterskip=.5cm
]{subsection}

 %ENDNOTENLAYOUT%
\renewcommand\enoteformat{\noindent\setlength\hangindent{0.5cm}\makebox[0.5cm][l]{\theenmark\,}}
\def\enotesize{\footnotesize}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\enoteheading{%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[
      beforeskip=3\baselineskip,
      afterskip=\baselineskip,
      font=\normalsize\itshape
    ]{section}%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Notes}

\let\footnote=\endnote

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\section{Beispiel}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection*{Endnotes}
\footnote{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[2]
\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1]

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

---

If you have a really **old KOMA-Script version (3.14 or older)** then ist is easier to use `titlesec`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Spacing between section and text
% Syntax: \titlespacing*{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0cm}{1cm}{0.5cm}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{1cm}{1cm}

 %ENDNOTENLAYOUT%
\renewcommand\enoteformat{\noindent\setlength\hangindent{0.5cm}\makebox[0.5cm][l]{\theenmark\,}}
\def\enotesize{\footnotesize}
%
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\enoteheading{%
  \titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{3\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}%
}{}{\PatchFailed}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{\normalsize\textit{Notes}}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\section{Beispiel}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection*{Endnotes}
\footnote{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[2]
\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1]

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I try your code it throws the following error:  Undefined control sequence. [\RedeclareSectionCommand]

Comment: @mvp285286 Then you have an old KOMA-Script version. The command was indroduced in 3.15. Current version is 3.20.  But I have added an example with `titlesec`.